# How to sum a simple csv file column in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Beginner here, so sorry in advance for any stupid questions. I'm having trouble summing the column "Value" in the following simple csv file data set. Does anyone know how I could do this? I've included the code and output below:

Text:

```
import pandas as pd
file_name = "Roll_Data.csv"
pd.read_csv(file_name,delimiter='\t').dropna()
```

Output

```
Roll, Value

1     9.0
2     3.0
3     8.0
4     2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Choose "Value" series in your dataframe and call sum()

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = "Roll_Data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name,delimiter='\t').dropna()
df["Value"].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Just curious, what does "df" do/mean? I've seen it a lot before when trying to figure this out and just curious if I should know how to use it.

Comment: df is the standard abbreviation for 'dataframe'.

Comment: Pandas return dataframe after reading csv. It's the object you showed printed to output in your question. It's full of helpful functions that work on `df` as well as `df["column"]`.